# Excel power query connection with DB2

Tags: database, db2, powerquery

I am trying to connect excel power query with DB2 database but i am getting 'user not authorized error'. I am entering the correct username and password. Please help.

Comment: Have you checked that you're authorized to the table?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes i have read writes on the tables and i am able to connect one table to excel using the Data tab but in order to connect more than one table i have to use power query option and i am not able to connect to database using power query. Not sure what is the issue.

Comment: Which DB2 driver are you using?

Comment: DB2 Runtime Client 10.5.3 this is the driver we are using.

Comment: The fastest way to check if it is security error is to give your user temporary dbo rights. If the error goes away, you need to double-check their permissions. If it doesn't - it is authorization problem and should be investigated further.

Comment: okay thanks so much for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is related to 32-bit vs 64-bit. Power Query is very picky about what drivers it can use to access database content. If it’s a 32-bit version of Excel, you need the 32-bit driver installed and vice versa.

So, if the versions are mismatched Power Query can’t work on your machine.

The solution in this case would be to get a 32-bit version of DB2 client installed.

Here’s more details:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-an-IBM-DB2-database-Power-Query-0163e2e8-2944-4f24-85c0-10ecb1bc731f